# Unable to create pause and resume functionality in an Audio recording app.Windows 8.1 Store App

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-store

I'm trying to produce a pause and resume functionality using the following code.

```
private async void RecordBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (IsNewRecording)
   {
         mediaFile = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFileAsync("newFile.mp3", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
         MediaEncodingProfile encodingProfile = null;
         switch (SelectedFormat)
         {
             case AudioEncodingFormat.Mp3:
             encodingProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp3(SelectedQuality);
             break;
             case AudioEncodingFormat.Mp4:
             encodingProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateM4a(SelectedQuality);
             break;
             case AudioEncodingFormat.Wma:
             encodingProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWma(SelectedQuality);
             break;
             default:
             throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
          }

          await CaptureMedia.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(encodingProfile, mediaFile);
          UpdateRecordingControls(RecordingMode.Recording);
          DishTimer.Start();
          IsNewRecording = false;
          RecordBtn.Content = "Pause";
          return;
     }
    else if (!IsNewRecording && !IsPaused)
    {
         UpdateRecordingControls(RecordingMode.Paused);
         DishTimer.Stop();
         await CaptureMedia.StopRecordAsync();
         IsPaused = true;
         RecordBtn.Content = "Resume";
         return;
     }
     else if (!IsNewRecording && IsPaused)
     {
          MediaEncodingProfile encodingProfile = null;
          encodingProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp3(SelectedQuality);
          await CaptureMedia.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(encodingProfile, mediaFile);
          DishTimer.Start();
          IsPaused = false;
          RecordBtn.Content = "Pause";
          return;
     }
 }
```

For stopping the recording.

```
private async void StopBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      await CaptureMedia.StopRecordAsync();
      UpdateRecordingControls(RecordingMode.Stopped); 
      DishTimer.Stop();
      InitTimer();
      IsNewRecording = true;
      RecordBtn.Content = "Record";   

 }
```

And for Initializing the MediaCapture.

```
private async Task InitMediaCapture()
{
     CaptureMedia = new MediaCapture();
     captureInitSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
     captureInitSettings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Audio;
     await CaptureMedia.InitializeAsync(captureInitSettings);
     CaptureMedia.Failed += MediaCaptureOnFailed;
     CaptureMedia.RecordLimitationExceeded += MediaCaptureOnRecordLimitationExceeded;

}
```

and the OnNavigatedTo event is as follows.

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
      await InitMediaCapture();// Mic disconnection Exception thrown if no device is found
      LoadAudioEncodings();
      LoadAudioQualities();
      UpdateRecordingControls(RecordingMode.Initializing);
      InitTimer();

 }
```

Also the other problem that I'm facing is that when  the App is minimized or the window is locked and the recording is started again `MediaCapture` Failed event is raised, giving the following error message.

The error message is:"The media device cannot go from stopped state to paused state", Even when the `MediaCapture` doesn't have the Pause method supported in Windows 8.1.

Also currently the recording is saved in the Music Library folder but What Can I do to save the recording in a particular folder in C drive.

Please help me with this !

Answer (score 0):

I've no experience with the streaming, but on the save part you could use the fileSavePicker. According to your code the recording should generate a StorageFile.

```
var fileSavePicker = new FileSavePicker();
fileSavePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add(".mp3 audio", new List { ".mp3" });
fileSavePicker.DefaultFileExtension = “.mp3”;
fileSavePicker.SuggestedFileName = “name.mp3”;
fileSavePicker.SettingsIdentifier = "pickerName";
fileSavePicker.SuggestedSaveFile = //your storage file here
fileSavePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = //select start location

var file = await fileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

if (file != null)
{
    Windows.Storage.CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(file);

    //override file with content, text example below
    //await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "yourconten");

    Windows.Storage.Provider.FileUpdateStatus status = 
        await Windows.Storage.CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(file);

    if (status == Windows.Storage.Provider.FileUpdateStatus.Complete)
    {
        //operation done
    }
    else
    {
        //something went wrong
    }
}
```

More information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-save-a-file-with-a-picker

Comment: thanks but, what I want to do is save the file to a location of my choice without prompting a FilePicker, something like I give the complete path for the file to be saved and the file gets saved in that location.